# Oozie validation command throwing Error: One file must be specified

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, scheduled-tasks, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to use validate method expose by oozie but stuck with error mentioned below.
As per Apache Documentation: 
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Validating_a_Workflow_XML

`oozie validate xx_logger_import/workflow.xml -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie
Error: One file must be specified`

Cloudera CDH-5.8 version is in use.
Oozie Version:

```
oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie  -version
Oozie server build version: 4.1.0-cdh5.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The workflow xml that you are trying to validate should be the last parameter in your validate command -

Example - 
**oozie validate -oozie $Oozie_URL /home/abc/workflow.xml**

Valid workflow-app

- oozie validate   : validate a workflow, coordinator, bundle XML file

  ```
               -auth <arg>    select authentication type [SIMPLE|KERBEROS]
               -oozie <arg>   Oozie URL
  ```

  *

Comment: what if oozie is running on remote server and launching the command from another server, oozie URL has to be there?

Comment: you will need oozir url , even if you are not working remotely .
either export the oozie url or put it in environment variables or pass it in command with -oozie <url >

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are passing the `-oozie` parameter as well. Just use the validate command and pass the required workflow file. Thanks.

```
oozie validate xx_logger_import/workflow.xml
```